# ipv4 and ipv6 displayed together

Tags: php, ip

I'm currently doing a website that shows the visitor's ip that includes IPv4 and IPv6 but it seems that I can't display them together if the visitor has both ips.

```html
<p>IPv4: <?php

                                        if(filter_var($getIP, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4)) {
                                            echo $remoteIP;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo "N/A";
                                        }

                                        ?></p>
                                    <p>IPv6: <?php

                                        if ( ipv6::isIPv6($remoteIP) ) {
                                            echo $remoteIP;
                                        } else {
                                            echo "N/A";
                                        }

                                        ?></p>
```

GetIPv6
This code checks for user if he has IPv6 as his IP

```php
<?php
class ipv6 {
    function get_ip() {
        return getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    }
    function isIPv6($ip = "") {
        if ($ip == "") {
            $ip = ipv6::get_ip();
        }
        if (substr_count($ip,":") > 0 && substr_count($ip,".") == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$remoteIP= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

GetIPv4

Just getting the IPv4, the most standard ip

```html
<?PHP

function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}

$getIP = getUserIP();

?>
```

Comment: how does a visitor have "both ips"?

Comment: Visitors that have ipv4 and ipv6. Like how http://whatip.me/ does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> …but it seems that I can't display them together if the visitor has both ips.

That's because that information isn't available.

The `REMOTE_ADDR` environment variable will only ever contain one IP address -- the one that the visitor used to reach your server. The only way to detect other addresses would be to force the browser to make another request which is only possible over IPv4 (or v6), e.g. by making a request to a domain which doesn't have an IPv6 (or v4) address.

Comment: so some kind of:
ipv4.example.com
and
ipv6.example.com?